# Approximation near singularity of $1/\sin$

Tags: functions, approximation, singularity

I'm looking for an approximation $f(x)$ of $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ near the singularity at $x=0$.

[image]

Can you propose a function or literature or a key word, which leads me to $f(x)$? $f(x)$ must not have a singularity at $x=0$ and needs to be continous.

Comment: Your request is somewhat contradictory. The closer you get to $x=0$, the more impossible is becomes to approximate under the given conditions.

Answer (score 2):

We have that by Taylor's expansion

$$\sin x = x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)$$

therefore

$$\frac1{\sin x}=\frac1{x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+O(x^7)}=\frac1x\frac1{1-\frac16x^2+\frac1{120}x^4+O(x^6)}=\frac1x\left(1+\frac16x^2+\frac7{360}x^4+O(x^6)\right)=$$

$$=\frac1x+\frac16x+\frac7{360}x^3+O(x^5)$$

then we can eliminate the singularity by a suitable factor for the $\frac1x$ term that is for example

$$\frac{1-e^{1000x^2}}x+\frac16x+\frac7{360}x^3+O(x^5)$$

Comment: Is it correct, that this term also have a singularity at $x=0$?

Comment: @Alex44 Yes it's a good approximation indeed for $x \to 0$.

Comment: I see, I did not ask clear enough what I am looking for.

Comment: @Alex44 Sorry! What kind of approximation you are looking for?

Comment: I added a sentence to my request to make it more clear. It shall look like the red curve from my post.

Comment: Ok I’ll take a look to it!

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by anything that is close to $1$ far from $x=0$ and has a minimum at $(0,0)$.

Like

$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+\epsilon)\sin(x)}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may not the best approximation:

$f(x) = k\left(\sin\left(sign(x) \cdot \left|x\right|^c \cdot \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) + x\right)$

[image]

The solution for $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=f(x)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)'=f'(x)$ for a fixed $k$ and a variable $c$ is hard to find.

Better proposals are welcome.